# Massive error line appearing when trying to use CMake?

Tags: cmake

Basically every time I try generate on CMake after successfully configuring it responds with a huge error line, I have read this but I don't understand what it means. I downloaded a GLFW file from the official GLFW website, (version 3.18). Please help me because I really want to learn OpenGL.

```
  Cannot find source file:

    clipboard.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    events.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    msaa.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    glfwinfo.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    iconify.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    monitors.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    reopen.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    cursor.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    empty.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    gamma.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    icon.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:50 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    inputlag.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    joysticks.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:54 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    threads.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    opacity.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:53 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    tearing.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    timeout.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    title.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    triangle-vulkan.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    windows.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: clipboard


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: events


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: msaa


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: glfwinfo


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: iconify


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: monitors


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: reopen


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: cursor


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: empty


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: gamma


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: icon


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:50 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: inputlag


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: joysticks


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:54 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: threads


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: opacity


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:53 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: tearing


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: timeout


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: title


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: triangle-vulkan


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: windows
```

How do I fix this, also here is the file I downloaded from GLFW for Visual Studio 2019.
File (not a rickroll, don't worry): http://www.mediafire.com/file/576nmghv6bbt36y/GLFW_Error_Files.zip/file

Comment: It seems your archive doesn't contain `clipboard.c` and other files for some reason. Moreover, the content of archive doesn't resemble official [glfw](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/tree/master).